# Acquire Access Token from Dropbox Oauth Redirect Using Vue Router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I am working with Dropbox JS SDK and implementing OAuth2 using the getAuthenticationUrl method.  This method requires a redirect url which when implemented opens a new tab with a url: http://localhost:8080/dropbox#access_token=ABCDEFG&token_type=bearer&uid=123456789&account_id=123456789

The component that starts the process contains:

```
   created() {
        dropBx = new Dropbox({ fetch: fetch, clientId: this.dropboxAppKey })
        authUrl = dropBx.getAuthenticationUrl('http://localhost:8080/dropbox')
        window.open(`${authUrl}`)
    },
```

My route looks like this:

```
    {
        path: '/dropbox',
        name: 'DropboxAuthFlow',
        component: () => import('@/views/DropboxAuthFlow.vue'),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: false,
            dropbox: true,
        },
    },
```

I am using history mode.  I have a route guard in place that looks like:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
        if (user) {
            next()
        } else {
            next({ name: 'LoginPage' })
        }
    } else if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.dropbox)) {
        next({ name: 'DropboxAuthFlow' })
    } else {
        next()
    }
})
```

The redirect to a new browser tab acts as if I am not logged in and does not show the component as expected.  The redirect uri is authorized in the dev console:  http://localhost:8080/dropbox

So questions:

```
1)  How can I get the redirect URL to work with Vue Router 
and display the URL despite the hash info?
2)  How can I parse the access token off the returned URL? 
(will $route.hash work?)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution...first change router guard:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
        if (user) {
            next()
        } else {
            next({ name: 'LoginPage' })
        }
    } else {
        next()
    }
})
```

Second...change route:

```
    {
        path: '/dropbox',
        name: 'DropboxAuthFlow',
        component: () => import('@/views/DropboxAuthFlow.vue')
    },
```

Finally change URI redirect page:

```
    created() {
        let hash = this.$route.hash
        let token = hash.substring(hash.indexOf('=') + 1, hash.indexOf('&'))
        // pass token via dispatch action to persist data in db
    },
```

I hope this helps someone who faces this problem...still open to other/better solutions.